# Edge shader using GLSL-ES

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, 3d, vertex-shader, glsles

I'm trying to do an edge shader but I have places where the edges are not shown at all. The behaviour is shown in the following image.

[image]

As you see the way I look at the model, doesn't show edges, but the other places are very sharp and looks good.

here is my attempt

```
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

varying vec3 normFrag;
void main()
{     

      vec4 pos_transformed = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertex;          
      vec3 normalizedNormal = normalize(normal);
      vec3 norm = mat3(normalMatrix)* normalizedNormal ;

      norm.y *=projection_matrix[2][3];
      norm.x *= projection_matrix[3][2];  

      //norm *=-1.0;
      norm = normalize(norm);

      pos_transformed.xy -= pos_transformed.z*norm.xy*0.005;

      gl_Position = vec4(pos_transformed);
}
```

Comment: Is there a description on how exactly are you trying to achieve this? A source from where you started with this shader and maybe what exactly it is doing or rather why is it doing that line by line (of code). Also what is your fragment shader. Original scene image would be nice as well so we could analyze where exactly the edges are drawn and where they are missing completely or why there are those large surfaces... And to begin with we can only assume from code that this is not a photo but an actual 3D scene, is that correct?

Comment: Also provide your fragment shader, since that is where you are probably clipping pixels early to get the actual edges to show up. my guess is you may have to increase the threshold for what is considered an "edge"